# Groovy tree-like sort

Tags: sorting, groovy, tree

I have a problem with sorting rows from db having tree-like hierarchy. Each row contains three columns meaningful to this problem: id, parent, lp. Id is String, parent is another row and lp is a number used to sort rows having no parent-child relationship. Each row can have any number of children and only one parent (null on top level)

There are three situations I see:

- when first row is parent of another: -1 is returned
- when first row is child of a parent with lower lp than another row::
  -1 is returned
- when none of those relations exist (also when rows have same parent and are on the same level) : to lps of rows are compared

I manadged to write this code that I think should solve the problem but it doesnt work for rows that are deep in hierarchy and it messes the order :

```
  dane = dane.sort {it1, it2 -> 
        it1 == it2.parent ? -1 :                                
           it1.parent && it1.parent.lp < it2.lp ? -1 :
               it1.lp - it2.key.lp                                  
   }
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison should be consistent regardless of the order of the arguments.  If the arguments are `a = it1` and `b = it2`, the result should be the negation of `b = it1` and `a = it2`.  It doesn't look like that's the case here.  For example, the case where `it1.parent == it2`.